# Unable to partition a SDXC card using Disk Utility

Tags: disk-utility, partition, sd-card

I have placed 200GB SanDisk card inside Nifty adapter and put it into SDXC slot in my Mac.

I want to use it as permanent & encrypted storage. Unfortunately encryption requires GUID partition which I tried to create but without any luck. "Partition" option - under "APPLE SD Card Reader Media" in Disk Utility - is greyed out.

[image]

I'm stuck.

P.S. I own Late 2013 Macbook Pro Retina 13" with MacOS Sierra (v10.12.6) installed.

Comment: It will probably be supplied as MBR, so you need to Erase first. Partition doesn't let you change the underlying format, MBR->GUID

Comment: @Tetsujin I've already erased that card and changed its format from ExtFAT to MacOS Extended (Journaled). I supplied gif with more information regarding my problem.

Comment: It's still MBR.[partition map Master Boot Record] It needs to be GUID. You can only do that from Erase.

Comment: Okay, found it :) I can choose partition map when erasing storage. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will probably be supplied as MBR, so you need to **Erase** first.
**Partition** doesn't let you change the underlying Partition Map format, MBR->GUID